# How to get lat long of first option from google map autocomplete result

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am trying to get first result from the google map autocomplete field on blur event as well as **place_changed** from autocomplete field and partially succeed in it.

But I have facing a problem, when blur event get fired, I am getting the first result from the first option in autocomplete field, but the result is not proper, so I am not getting the exact lat long.

For example if I search for the word "Nimblechapps" The result is from place_change event is **"Nimblechapps Pvt Ltd, Prahlad Nagar, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India"**, but when blur event fired the result is what I am getting is **"Nimblechapps Pvt LtdPrahlad Nagar, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India"**. You can see the difference in both the results. There is a small deference of comma after **Pvt. Ltd**.

Below is my code to achieve it. I have taken reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772282/google-maps-places-api-v3-autocomplete-select-first-option-on-enter-and-have#answer-10772424)

```js
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('location')),{types: []});
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', onPlaceChanged);
$('#location').on('blur', function () {
    var firstResult = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();
    geocoder.geocode({"address": firstResult}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            infoWindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = results[0];
            if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
            }

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(12);
            }
            $('#lat').html(place.geometry.location.lat());
            $('#long').html(place.geometry.location.lng());
            $('#fLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
            $('#fLong').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            var address = '';
            console.log(place.geometry.location.toString());
            if (place.address_components)
            {
                address = [
                    (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(', ');
            }

            $('#location').val(firstResult);
            infoWindow.close();
            infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            infoWindow.close();

        }
    });
});
```

**Edit :** `var firstResult = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();`

I am getting wrong result here in firstResult variable

Comment: The issue is probably somewhere in the code where you combine the `place.address_components`. I recommend checking the address you get as a result for several different requests and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: @not_a_bot : I have added a Edit to my question.