# Prevent form submit on field enter key keydown?

Tags: javascript, forms

I've built a listener to prevent a form from submitting on a special ocasion.

I'm using google maps autocomplete api and basically I don't want to submit the form when the users press enter and the "recommended results box" is displayed. As the users are pressing enter to choose a value from the dropdown box and not to submit the form.

I've built a listener that catches the event correctly but I don't know how to prevent the form from being submitted.

```
$('body').live('keydown', function(e) {
    if($(".pac-container").is(":visible") && event.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
        }
    });
```

I tried with e.preventDefault(); but it still submits the form. The form ID is: `updateAccountForm`

How can I prevent it from happening?

EDIT:
I must point out that it seems that listening for keypresses directly on the search input conflicts with Google API invalidating the autocomplete functions. So no `$('input#search')` keydown/keypress is possible

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` and/or `return false;` after it, solve the problem?

Comment: I see now that you add listener on body. So the keypress event is fired after the input submit. Try to see `.bind` and see the third argument `preventBubble` (I'm not sure and I cannot test it now). Otherwise I think you should attach the listener in input field or attach a submit listener on form.

Comment: I honestly cannot make out what to do from your suggestion. Please add it as a question and I'll test it! thanks

Comment: done! I'm tested and it works.

Comment: Have you checked that you actually got anything in `event.keyCode`? It looks like you are using jQuery so you should check `e.which `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try using something like this … wrapping in a check for the visibility of your container

```
$('body').keypress(function(e) 
{
  if (e.keyCode == '13') {
     e.stopPropagation()

   }
});​
```

The article [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) has a good explanation.

Comment: this didn't work for me, because by the time the keypress event was fired the .pac-container has already disappeared (I notice you haven't got the original posters condition to check .pac-container visibility). So the way this works, **all** form submissions with Enter will be rejected which won't really work. The only answer that seemed to work was Liso22 suggestion below.

Comment: Also there is an error in the *if* clause, keyCode is not a string:
`if (e.keyCode == 13)`

Answer (score 5):

The solution was actually pretty simple. All listeners seemed to fail however adding:

```
onkeydown="if($('.pac-container').is(':visible') && event.keyCode == 13) {event.preventDefault();}"
```

Directly to the input did the trick.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what exactly do you mean when you say "adding it directly to the input"?

Comment: He means to add it directly to the input tag thusly:
<input onkeydown="..." />

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('body').live('keydown', function(e) {
    if($(".pac-container").is(":visible") && e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent form submission
    }
});
```

please see `e`.keyCode instead of `event`.keyCode
and `e.stopPropagation()` instead of `e.preventDefault`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the enter key from submitting a form on a [Google Places API autocomplete's text field](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms), I needed a **keydown** handler...

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#my-autocomplete', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('#my-autocomplete').show();
      return false;
    }
});
```

... and a **place_changed** listener attached to the autocomplete after it was instantiated :

```
var my_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(/*...*/);
google.maps.event.addListener(my_autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = my_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.place_id) { return; }
});
```

Not that it matters, *but it might*, this solution worked inside a jQuery Mobile web app.

Comment: I think the above first code example is sufficient as it allows you to target a specific element and not just the whole document. You may want to use enter every where "except" on a particular element(s). Not sure why there was no up vote. I guess the OP needed some functionality with google maps, as for me I needed no such solution other than to target and element and prevent submission when pressing "Enter/Return".

Answer (score 0):

preventing form submission

```
 <form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="search">

    </form>
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    <script>
        $('input#search').keypress(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == '13') {
             e.preventDefault();

           }
        });​
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried this before I should have pointed it out. It seems that Google API invalidates either intently or not the autocomplete input if you add a keypress listener directly to it. That's why I was trying to listen to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant question: [Google maps Places API V3 autocomplete - select first option on enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865446/google-maps-places-api-v3-autocomplete-select-first-option-on-enter/11703018#11703018)

When I used the Google Maps Autocomplete box I wanted to make 'enter' and 'tab' select the first item. I followed @amirnissim 's solution linked above, to simulate a down arrow key press if either enter/tab are pressed from the input element.

When I coded it I didn't have those inputs as part of a form. I'm not sure how to prevent the form from sending on enter key (in fact that's how I found this question) but when I used Autocomplete my input was not part of a form.