# How to order addEventlistener in Ember. Want to execute my eventListener before 3rd party on same element

Tags: ember.js

Hi I am trying to do things with emberjs and google maps.
The issue with google autocomplete api is if user enters text in location search but does not select any value from dropdown suggestion in textbox the first suggestion is not selected. I found a good solution for it on stack overflow [solutiion in jquery only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11703018/433271)
I am trying to do it in ember.

```
App.AutocompleteAddressView = Ember.TextField.extend({
tagName: 'input',
autocomplete: null,

didInsertElement: function () {
    this._super();
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: "xx"
        }
    };
    this.set('autocomplete', new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.$()[0], options));
    //var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.$()[0], options);

},
keyDown: function (e) {
    var that = this;
    var suggestion_selected = $(".pac-item.pac-selected").length > 0;
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && !suggestion_selected) {
        //key down arrow simulations
        var event = Ember.$.Event('keypress', {
            keyCode: 40
        });
        Ember.run(this.$("#searchTextField"), 'trigger', event);

        console.log('loggin autocomplete');
        console.log(this.get('autocomplete'));

        //adding google map event and then triggering it
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.get('autocomplete'), 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = that.get('autocomplete').getPlace();
            that.set('autocomplete_result', place)
            console.log('google event was triggered');
            console.log(that.get('autocomplete_result'));
        });
        google.maps.event.trigger(this.get('autocomplete'), 'place_changed');
    }
}
```

});

Now I need to do simulation part. I guess ember testing has somthing that simulates keypress but I cannot used it.

1. If I use the solution from the link I mentioned things work fine first time but on clicking browser back navigation it does not work.
2. The solution I tried in code not working