# Trigger a button click on the Enter key in a text box misses its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

#### Html:

```
<form  action="" method="post"  id="contactForm">
    <input id='inputbox' name="inputbox" type="text" />
    <button type="button" id='search'> search </button>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputbox").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#search").click();
        }
    });

    $('#search').click(function(){
         var inputbox= $("#inputbox").val();  
        //stuff
    });
});
```

**inputbox** value is nothing when I press enter, however if I click on button It works perfectly with same input value

maybe making  **inputbox** global?

Comment: Did you try `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode` ? Did you prevent the form from submitting!

Comment: Try `$("#search").trigger("click");`

Comment: @adeneo - that won't matter, jQuery has that built in.

Comment: What about $('#contactForm').submit();

Comment: @Titanium - Nope, jQuery [normalizes event.which](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), but not keyCode.

Comment: That's what I meant - jQuery normalises it. The point is, you don't have to worry about it. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the enter key defaults to submitting your form, even without a submit button. So you should block the submission by changing the event binding to `keypress` and using `event.preventDefault()`, like this:

```
$("#inputbox").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#search").click();
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `.submit()` to trigger your function, change the input type to submit, and avoid separate handling for keys and clicks.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contactForm">
    <input id='inputbox' name="inputbox" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactForm").submit(submitSearch);
}); 

function submitSearch(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     //do other stuff
     alert($("#inputbox").val());
}
```