# Why jQuery's event.which gives different results in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, keycode

Have a look at [this live demo](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/#example-0) (from jQuery's site).

Clicking `-` (dash) in Firefox says that `event.which` is `173`, while doing the same in Chrome produces `189`.

[This jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object) says that `event.which` should be normalized for cross browser consistency. But, it looks like this is not true.

Why is this inconsistency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This jQuery page says that event.which should be normalized for cross browser consistency. But, it looks like this is not true.

jQuery normalizes the property *name* (e.g., always `which`, rather than `which` or `keyCode` depending on browser), but not the *value* of the property, which would be dramatically more complex.

The value for the key you get from `keydown` / `keyup` will vary not only by browser, but by keyboard layout. There are lots of gory details on the [*JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events*](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) page by Jan Wolter. Amongst other things, you can see on that page that for that key, Firefox will give you 109, IE (and apparently Chrome) will give you 189, and Opera apparently used to go with 45 (but in my tests on Linux, they now go with 109).

For printable keystrokes (like `-`), you're better off with the `keypress` event, which gives you the resulting *character*.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.11, it does not appear that jQuery fully normalizes the `event.which` property, at least under FireFox. As can be seen here: http://jsbin.com/sozoqiro/1/edit?html,console `event.which` and `event.keyCode` both have different values depending on what key you press.  Pressing a printing character seems to populate `e.which` while the Tab key for instance populates `e.keyCode` and the Enter key populates both `e.which` and `e.keyCode` with the same value. In FireFox, the unpopulated property value is set to `0`.

Comment: In Chrome, this seems to be normalized, but `keypress` does not seem to trigger for Tab keys in Chrome.