# event.preventdefault is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, preventdefault

I am trying to make the partial text in Input filed as read only, to achieve that I found this code but it is not working in FIrefox, works fine in chrome.

Found that event.preventDefault is causing the problem.
Tried return false, that is also not working.

**Angular JS Directive code**

```
app.directive('partialReadonly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {

            $element.on('keypress, keydown', function (event) {
                var readOnlyLength = attrs["partialReadonly"].length;

                if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
                        && (($element[0].selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
                                || (($element[0].selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
                    alert('preventdef');
                    //return false;
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            $scope.load = function () {
                alert('load called attrs["partialReadonly"] ' + attrs["partialReadonly"]);
                $scope.temp = attrs["partialReadonly"];
                // $element[0].value = attrs["partialReadonly"];

            };

        }
    };
});
```

Html code

```
 <input type="text"  ng-init="load()" ng-model="key" partial-readonly="{{number}}" />
```

Comment: It's a long shot - Try switching the alert with the preventDefault

Comment: do not use alert to debug...

Comment: It might be that the problem is not on preventDefault. It might be on `event.which`. Refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177818/why-jquerys-event-which-gives-different-results-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: @AlonEitan Your long shot was damn correct! Thanks.

Comment: What did you expect and what did you get instead? "Not working" is the character set which convinces me to not allocate time for the problem.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for suggestion, it did work work me.

Comment: @LajosArpad By not working I meant the functionality it was suppose to block, as in this case it was to block entering of other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @epascarello and @Alon don't use alert for debugging instead use console logs, Removing alert from your script might help.

Hope i helped