# Keyboard shortcut ctrl+r not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the snippet below, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (`event.which == 13`) is working. However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (`event.which == 9`) is not.

```
if ($('.selector')) {                 
  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.altKey && event.which == 13 ) {                  
      $('.link a').trigger('click');                          
    } else if ( event.altKey && event.which == 82 ) {           
      $('.link a').trigger('click');     
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You're testing for a tab `9 == tab`

Comment: I don't think that combination will ever work because `Ctrl + R` is reserved for "reloading". Not sure though.

Comment: Also they `keyCode` for `r` isn't `9`.

Comment: Ooop, I was testing other combinations. Maybe I should clarify. No combination of ctrl+(character) works.

Comment: @ScottMagdalein - Did you try keycode 114 and add `event.preventDefault()` at the end?

Comment: Maybe has something to do with `event.altKey` vs `event.ctrlKey` ?

Comment: @elclanrs - `keyPress` doesn't listen for the `tab` key unless you are using Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the `keyPress` listener [behaves differently](http://blog.pothoven.net/2008/05/keydown-vs-keypress-in-javascript.html) and uses a different set of keyCode. For `keyPress` the `r` key is `114` while for `keyDown` it is `82`.

Also another problem is browser's default reload function will override your function because keypress is executed after you release the key. To solve this, change `keypress` to `keydown`.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey){    //keycode is 82 for keydown
        alert("Pressed!");
        e.preventDefault();             //stop browser from reloading
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/3P9NS/show

**PS:** It seems like Firefox is ignoring `e.preventDefault` (which by W3C standards it should). The best thing to do to support all browsers is to choose another combination, or use `ctrl + alt + r`.

```
if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey && e.altKey){
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Changed a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but still, I think we have now **the best thing**. I tested my example in almost all browsers. No need to mix the `ALT` key in our story

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Indeed your solution does work in this case, but personally I don't think doing that is good for further maintenance.

Comment: I might agree with you, but there's AFAIK right now no other choice but to do it that way. What you mean exactly with maintenance?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Well if in the future you want to add another combination or Firefox decided to change it, you will have to rewrite your code and it looks troublesome.

Comment: as for jQuery dropped `$.browser` from the API, believe me that `userAgent` is a killer. There more if you look at my code, if Chrome team changes the operation of those ones, there's always the `which` that used by jQuery tries always to be as xBrowsr compatible as possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which So I think as it stands right now we have a possible Future-proof solution

Answer (score 1):

Based on some quick testing at http://api.jquery.com/event.which/, it seems you want `event.which == 82`, not `event.which == 9`.  Although most browsers tend to use Ctrl + R to refresh the page, so this might not be the best way to handle whatever you're doing.

Comment: I'm using that site I linked to as a test, and it says 82.

Comment: But you can see it says 114 in my fiddle.

Comment: Oh yeah, in JS `keypress` and `keydown` uses different sets of keyCode, that's why. It should be 114.

Comment: Wow, didn't know `keypress` uses a different set of keycodes. @Derek朕會功夫 do you know where I can find that list?

Comment: @ScottMagdalein, I'm suspicious the keycodes may be platform dependent.. or otherwise not well portable.

Comment: @ScottMagdalein - I couldn't find a full list right now, but meanwhile you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/KEnjw/2/

Comment: @ScottMagdalein - Also keep in mind that `keypress` [behaves differently than `keydown`](http://blog.pothoven.net/2008/05/keydown-vs-keypress-in-javascript.html), for example, it doesn't seem like it is picking direction keys, shift, tab, etc. (I don't know if it is a browser-specific thing or not).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Bingo!!! The problem was with using `keypress` with a combo (`ctrl + r` or `alt + r`). Thank you!

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 If you leave your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as solved. Also, the keycode that worked for r is 82.

Answer (score 1):

A cross-Browser solution to prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> refresh page:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/umareq/6/)** <sub>(works in **Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera**)</sub>

```
var keyEv = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox')>-1?["keypress",114]:["keydown",82];
$(document)[keyEv[0]](function(e) {
  if ( e.ctrlKey && e.which == keyEv[1] ){     
      e.preventDefault();      
      alert("CTRL+R");  
    }
});
```

By simply testing for our `navigator.userAgent` you can decide what Key event listener to use and the respective `R` key code.

---

If you need to handle both <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in combination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> than you just need this little tweak:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/umareq/9/)** (again all browsers :) )

```
var keyEv = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox')>-1?["keypress",114]:["keydown",82];
$(document)[keyEv[0]](function(e) {
  var k = e.which;
  if ( e.ctrlKey && k==keyEv[1] || k==13 ){ // no XBrowser issues with 13(Enter)
                                            // so go for it!
      e.preventDefault();      
      alert("Do something here");  
  }
});
```

Comment: @ScottMagdalein figured out a nice solution to your problem. take a look

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - This is a really good solution only if he has 1 combination.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 he does not need any other combination. If you read carefully the question TITLE. The OP messed up a bit the `altKey` with `ctrlKey` and the relevant numbers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Did you even see the Ctrl + Enter combination in his code?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I don't see any problem to implement the ENTER key as well ... http://jsbin.com/umareq/9

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - well I guess you deserve the upvote from me :)