# Why the keyCode event for escape alone not working?

Tags: jquery, keypress, keycode

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
  alert(e.keyCode);
  if(e.keyCode==27)
  {
    hide_menu();
  }
});
```

I get the alert for all keys except the escape key and the success part of the `if` is never getting called. Why this happens?

Comment: Just a sidenote, you should be using [e.which if you're using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471635/1400370)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use **$(document).keyup** instead of **$(document).keypress**

the following code works fine:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) 
{
  alert(e.keyCode);

  if(e.keyCode==27)
  {
      alert ("Esc key");
      hide_menu();
  }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tb2BD/ Click in the output window and then press esc button. Works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `keypress` to `keyup`(*better to use keyup*) or `keydown`:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode==27){
       hide_menu();
    }
});
```