# Trigger <button> when pressing the Enter key in text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, button

I'm making a search bar with the text-bar as an  tag, and the search-button as a , the reason I use a  instead of  is because I'm using a picture of a magnifying glass on the button, an when I use  it doesn't want to position itself properly.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="search-form" href="#test1" class="smoothscroll">
            <input type="text" id="searchText" onClick="this.select();" placeholder="Search..."/>
            <button type="button" id="searchButton">
                <img src="magnify.png" id="magnify"/>
            </button>
        </form>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchButton").click(function () {
        var text = document.getElementById('searchText').value;
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: ($('#' + text).offset().top)
        }, 2000);
    });

    $("#searchText").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#searchButton").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Any reason why var text = document.getElementById('searchText').value; used instead of $('#searchText').val(); ???

Answer (score 2):

As per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), You should use `.which` instead of keyCode:

```
$("#searchText").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
        $("#searchButton").click();
    }
    // Make sure the form isn't submitted
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

> To determine which key was pressed, examine the event object that is
>   passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing
>   properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which
>   property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the key code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#searchText").keyup(function (event) {
    var code= event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    // or use simply, var code= event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        $("#searchButton").click();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KAHFt/)

Comment: Going to have to downvote this. jQuery normalizes the keyCode and which events, so there is no need for the ternary check here.

Comment: @RGraham what you think `// Make sure the form isn't submitted event.preventDefault();` is enough to `prevent form submit`. `$("#searchButton").click();` `submits` the `form` without `preventing`.

Comment: `searchButton` is not a submit button. The reason for adding this is so that when the user eventually *does* put a submit button in there (which I assume he will) pressing enter will not submit the form.

Comment: But it `submits` the `form`

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but where does he call submit? I can't see it

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#searchText").keyup(function(event){

  if (event.which === 13) {
    $("#searchButton").trigger("click");
   }  
});
```

also see [Javascript .keyCode vs. .which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which)