# Only Execute if Key is pressed Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, key

I have the following code:

```
onkeyup = function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 77) { // the 'm' key
           setTimeout(function () {
            ... // my set timeout stuff
            }
```

The problem is that every time I press the m key, my setTimeout re executes. 
How can I keep it so that only if I **press & hold** **once**, the setTimeout executes. (any more times and nothing should executed).

Thanks, should be simple enough I hope.

Comment: how about set a variable and check for it? like pressed = true inside the if block and if(e.keyCode == 77 && !pressed) in the condition.. plus an initial pressed = false outside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a Boolean variable like so:

```
var hasKeyBeenPressed = new Boolean(0);
```

In your setTimeout function, change this value to true.  On your conditional checking for the keycode, check and ensure the setTimeout function only executes when this boolean value has been set to false.

```
var hasKeyBeenPressed = new Boolean(0);

onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 77 && hasKeyBeenPressed == 0) { // the 'm' key
        setTimeout(function () {
            hasKeyBeenPressed = 1;
            ... // my set timeout stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Under these conditions, your function will execute only one time.

If you need some persistence, consider using sessionStorage.

Comment: Don't forget `e.which` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which.  Also, what's wrong with good old-fashioned `true` and `false`?