# send data with ajax when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a form like this :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="msg" id="chat_in" >
    <input type="button" name="bt" id="bt">
</form>
```

i want to send data when user pressing enter or clicking on button

it's work when user click on button , but it doesn't work when user pressing enter on `chat_in`

here is my javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function SendData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "post",
            data: "msg="+$('#chat_in').val(),
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(){   
                alert("Sent");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");                
            }
        });
    }

    $('#chat_in').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
            SendData();
        }
    });

    $('#bt').click(function() {
        SendData();
    });
});
```

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/pYP4s/); you  must have something else going on beyond what you've posted

Comment: bind ajax to submit event of form, not button click

Comment: @Crayon Violent it's not sending data when user pressing enter

Comment: @user3325376 well then perhaps you should have been more specific than "it doesn't work"

Comment: Use `e.keyCode` instead of `e.which`

Comment: @RyanJ both of them ( `e.keyCode ` and `e.which ` ) detecting enter key , but my problem is , data doesn't sent in this case...

Comment: But FYI i see a post request to save.php w/ `msg=[value]` in it. So I stick by my "something else going on here besides what you posted." @RyanJ [jquery normalizes `.which` vs. `.keyCode`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which) so that shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#chat_in").keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
   //call send data function here
    SendData();
} });
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

if anyone have same problem , just remove `form` and use `button`

in this case your html and javascript should be something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>final</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
function SendData() {
   $.ajax({
        url: "save.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "msg="+$('#chat_in').val(),
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(){   
            alert("Sent");
        },


        error:function(){
            alert("failure");

        }
    });


}   



$('#chat_in').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
        SendData();
    }



    });


$('#bt').click(function() {
SendData();


 });





});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="msg" id="chat_in" >
<input type="button" name="bt" id="bt">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move out `SendData` from `document.ready`

```
function SendData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "post",
            data: "msg="+$('#chat_in').val(),
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(){   
                alert("Sent");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");                
            }
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#chat_in').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
            SendData();
        }
    });

    $('#bt').click(function() {
        SendData();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be better to do this on the submit of the form. Browsers do the whole "enter" thing for you so you don't have to worry about it.

Add `id` to the `<form>` tag, and change the type from `button` to `submit`:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="msg" id="chat_in" >
    <input type="submit" name="bt" id="bt" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

Update you Javascript:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
        SendData();
});
```

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm64Q/)

Comment: it's not working and returning error ajax `error:function( {alert("failure");}`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use keyup function as "keypress" function behaves differently in different browsers.