# why does isAlphaNumeric javascript function works on Chrome but fails in IE 10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I need html input which allows only alphanumeric chars. Here is my input

```
<input type="text" id="l1t1r1c1" onkeypress="javascript:return isAlphaNumeric(event,this.value);" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 99.99, this)">
```

isAlphaNumeric javascript function works on Chrome but fails in IE 10. How can I run this function in IE10?

here is my function

```
function isAlphaNumeric(e) { // Alphanumeric only
            var k;
            document.all ? k = e.keycode : k = e.which;
            return ((k > 47 && k < 58) || k == 46 || k == 0);
        };
```

THX.

Comment: Why do you test if `document.all` exists? Don't you think it makes more sense to test if `e.keycode` exists?

Comment: try using onkeyup....

Comment: Good advice thx Mr Lister. I am using onkeyup for another func C-link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error. It is `keyCode` not `keycode`

```
function isAlphaNumeric(e) { // Alphanumeric only
        var k;
        document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
        return ((k > 47 && k < 58) || k == 46 || k == 0);
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckkY4/)

Comment: Yeah. your answer fixed my problem. but I am wondering how it worked on Chrome when it has syntax error? :D

Comment: do you know why you have two e.keyCode and e.which?? chrome will take the e.which property. Go through here for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which