# Keyup to Manipulate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

Haven't post in quite a while.

Anyway I was searching about my subject and I got this.

```
$(window).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 8) {
        $('.ilol'). fadeOut();
    }
});
```

It's working perfectly fine. But when I change the window to a class or id it doesn't respond anymore.

Comment: Have you made sure to use selectors for the jQuery? `'#id'`  `'.class'`

Comment: What element type does the ID or class belong to? Not all elements will make use of the `keyup` event.

Comment: what are you trying to achive? To fadeout when hit backspace?

Comment: I have tested a few things and noticed that it's working when the focus is in the input elements. I wonder if its possible to focus divs. And yes i want the div to fadeout when i hi backspace.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of detail about the type of element you are trying to attach this event handler to, but the jQuery documentation explains that form elements (e.g. `input`) are a safe bet because they are able to be focused across most browsers:

> The `keyup` event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on
>   the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only
>   sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can vary
>   between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

It may also be a selector issue. Make sure that your selector is working properly by pasting it in your browser's JavaScript console and see if it returns any elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are binding event in ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.someClassName').keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 8) {
          $('.ilol'). fadeOut();
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some testing this is what worked best for me. The 40 key in this example is the down arrow key.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        $('.ilol').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery uses `e.which` to abstract away the differences in the ways browsers detect key events. You [should use `which`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which) instead of `keyCode`.