# JavaScript Keyboard Key Code 0 in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following code and am trying to allow only 3 digits 0-9 in the input, but still allow the user to use the arrow keys, backspace, and delete keys.

It works in other browsers, but in firefox the output to the console shows the arrow keys and the delete key registering as key code 0. What gives?

Code:

```
$input.
    keypress(function(e) {
        var currentLength = $input.val().length;
        var c = e.which;
        console.log("key", c);
        //0=48, 9=57, 37-40 = arrow keys 8= backspace,  46=delete
        if (c === 8 || c === 46 || (c >= 37 && c <=40)) {
            //delete, backspace, and arrow keys are allowed
        } else if (c < 48 || c > 57 || currentLength >= 3) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }).on("paste", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2cjpdfcy/

Comment: On a minor note, event 'input' will only fire for keys that change the input value, so you wouldn't have to care about the arrow keys.

Comment: @Taplar That is a great suggestion but unfortunately I have to still support IE 8 :( Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var c = e.which;
```

with :

```
var c = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

And all will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/2cjpdfcy/2/

Comment: Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: @thatidiotguy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which

Comment: Ah, so this is a native event so the jQuery normalization does not happen. Interesting. Well you solution works, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the keycodes use `keyup` instead of `keypress`:

```
$input.keyup(function(e) {
    // your logic...
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cjpdfcy/1/)

Comment: So that definitely works, but would you mind explaining WHY this is the case? What is different about the keyup event? Also do you have any comment on Sergio's solution which also works?