# event.charCode, event.keyCode returns 0 and 229 on android 4.4

Tags: jquery, android-4.4-kitkat, keydown

I'm facing the following problem : 
After my android tablet update to Android 4.4, the **event** in KeyDown

```
$("#txtStudentAnswer").keydown(function (event) {});
```

event.charCode always returns 0 
event.keyCode always returns 229.
Any help ? Or alternative solutions ?
 This question is different than the on in [Javascript .keyCode vs. .which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which) , it's a tablet and android issue more than keyCode and which issue.

Comment: beside that `charCode` is deprecated: For a keydown event `charCode` should always be `0` because `[...]The KeyboardEvent.charCode read-only property returns the Unicode value of a character key pressed during a keypress event.[...]` ( [KeyboardEvent.charCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) ). For jQuery you should use `event.which` because ` [...]browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which property so you can reliably use it to retrieve[...]` ( [jQuery.keydown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/)  )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript .keyCode vs. .which?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which)

Comment: I have tried event.which and always it's returning 0. My code resemble to the following :  if (event.charCode || event.keyCode) {
            unicode = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
        }. Noting that the code is working normally on Chrome on Pc, and on firefox on tablet.