# Tab key is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the folling code, when it triggers the tab key is not working in firefox but works in chrome.

HTML:

```
<input id="contactPhone" onkeypress="validationPhone(event)" data-bind='value: phone' type="text" class="form-control" maxlength='10'>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
  validationPhone = function (x) {
      var evt = window.event || x;

      if ((evt.which > 46 && evt.which < 58) || evt.which == 8) {
          return true;
      }
      else {
          evt.preventDefault();
      }
  }
```

Comment: See this for why it won't work on firefox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which

Answer (score 0):

you are using Javascript Char Code , You can use char code 9 for tab and Instead of onkeypress use [onkeydown event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp)

Try With this :

HTML:

```
<input id="contactPhone" onkeydown="validationPhone(event)" data-bind='value: phone' type="text" class="form-control" maxlength='10'>
```

JS:

```
validationPhone = function (x) {
  var evt = window.event || x;

  if ((evt.which > 46 && evt.which < 58) || evt.which == 8 ||evt.which == 9) {
      return true;
  }
  else {
      evt.preventDefault();
  }
```

}