# Using jQuery to changing background colour of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background colour of my div when the user presses either <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd>. I need to use the keypress method, but for some reason my code doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event === 99) {
      $(".light").css('background-color', "#00ffff");
    } else if (event === 121) {
      $(".light").css('background-color', "#00ffff");
    } else if (event === 109) {
      $(".light").css('background-color', "#00ffff");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="light"></div>
```

Comment: Use `event.which` instead `event`.

Comment: Does your `.light` element have any height or content in it? If it doesn't you won't be able to see the background change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `event.which` to determine which key was pressed. Here's working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 99) {
      $(".light").css('background-color', "#00ffff");
    } else if (event.which === 121) {
      $(".light").css('background-color', "#00ffff");
    } else if (event.which === 109) {
      $(".light").css('background-color', "#00ffff");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.light {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="light"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `which` value from the keypress event. I would also suggest that you use a `switch`-statment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var color = null;

    switch (e.which || e.keyCode || 0) { // Cover all cases
      case 99:  // Key - C
        color = '#00FFFF'; break;
      case 109: // Key - M
        color = '#FF00FF'; break;
      case 121: // Key - Y
        color = '#FFFF00'; break;
      default:
        color = '#FFFFFF';
    }

    $('.light').css('background-color', color);
  });
});
```

```css
.light {
  width: 95vw;
  height: 95vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="light"></div>
```

---

Thanks to [**smarx**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94559/smarx) for the heads-up about [jQuery and which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which).

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which, I think `which` is preferred when using jQuery.