# jquery works only on firefox and not in other web browsers (chrome ,opera..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> Aspx code

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" onkeydown="keyPressed(event, 'txtSearch');" class="form-control" runat="server" ID="txtSearch">
</asp:TextBox>
```

> Js Code

```
function keyPressed(e, id) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var id = '<%= btnSearch.ClientID%>';
    $('#' + id).click();
  }
}
```

please suggest why it not working.Thanks in advance

Comment: Add more information about the OP

Comment: It works fine on mozilla firefox only and not in anyother web browsers . if anybody experienced this , please help ! @guradio

Comment: Some browsers use `keyCode`, others use `which`. If you're using jQuery, you can reliably use `which` ... See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which :D

Comment: changed as   e.keyCode == 13 || e.which ==13 still not working    @TaufikNurRahmanda

Comment: The code works perfectly fine in chrome, IE and firefox. I copied and pasted the same code and checked. What version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong in another code that's conflicting with your code. Try to add `console.log('pressed key: '+e.which)` in the first line and check it in the console :)

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda checked , entered keycode is 13 , same condition till now ? should i need to upgdate my browser ?

Comment: @AnoopH.N jquery version is 2.2.4