# Why does e.keyCode does not catch "{" in my textarea when typing on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, keycode

I am using an android phone and when I press any key in my textarea, it looks like that e.keycode does not function properly (It does not return true the keycode value for each key). But it always triggers when I press any key in my textarea.

```js
function d(e) {
  var key = (e.keyCode);
  if (key == 229) {
    alert("hello");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="msg" onkeyup="d(event)"> 
</textarea>
```

NOTE: For testing purposes, use your mobile phone (specifically android phone) to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov: No. It would be `e.which`, but given the OP's quoted symptom, it's not that they're using the wrong property (but it's unclear what *is* wrong).

Comment: You forgot } at the end

Comment: *"But it always triggers when I press any key in my textarea."* There's nothing obvious in the quoted code that would cause that. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem. (I've added the snippet for you, but it doesn't do what you describe.)

Comment: @aokaddaoc still the same the problem exist

Comment: Well you can solve it by `console.log(e)`

Comment: You've clearly been back since the comments above. Why don't you address them, and make it possible to answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

`219` is the keyCode which need to be used

```js
function d(e) {
  var key = (e.keyCode);

  if (key == 219) {
    alert("hello");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="msg" onkeyup="d(event)"> 
 </textarea>
```

Comment: Which doesn't account for the symptom described by the OP.

Answer (score -1):

The keycode for `{` is `219`. Some browser uses `keycode`, some uses `which`. There is also `charCode`.

```js
function d(e){
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode || 0;
    if (key == 219){
         alert("hello");
         return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="msg" onkeyup="d(event)"> 
</textarea>
```

Comment: None of which accounts for the symptom described by the OP.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder isn't he using the wrong the keycode for `{` ?

Comment: Probably, but the question clearly says it **always** triggers, not that it never triggers. The question can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: I thought when it meant is when OP presses any button it is triggering the `d()` . I agree that question is not clear.