# Pressing enter to submit form in react-testing-library does not work

Tags: reactjs, forms, events, jestjs, react-testing-library

#### Description:

I am trying to test that a form submits when the user presses the "Enter" key. I have a passing test for when pressing the `Submit` button, but I also want to be sure the form submits with the keyboard (convenience and a11y).

#### Code:

```js
test("should submit when pressing enter", () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<App handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />);
  const input = getByLabelText("Name:");

  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "abc" } });
  fireEvent.keyPress(input, { key: "Enter", code: 13, charCode: 13 });

  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-jackson-pdd5h) with the minimal amount of code needed.

Answer (score 18):

The following worked for me:

```js
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

test("should submit when pressing enter", () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<App handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />);
  const input = getByLabelText("Name:");

  userEvent.type(input, "abc{enter}");

  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I don't have onsubmit prop on my component. I have onkeydown function . When i press enter key on input onkeydown function calls and from there i am submitting the form. So how can i spyon for onkeydown method. I want to check my function calling or not. Please help

Comment: You can check if the view updates according to what happens after the submit function is executed. For example, if you type enter, the form submits and a div with "Form Submitted" pops up, you can check if an element with that text exists. However, if you really need to check if that function executes, then you can jest.spyOn any utility functions that submit function calls.

Comment: I tried jest.spyon(component.prototype, 'method'); but i am getting an error like can't spyon premitive value. In my component onkeydown is a function and i am submitting form from there. I want to check onkeydown calling or not using spyon.

Comment: oh sorry I should have clarified. I meant that if your component method calls any utility functions that are imported like lodash, fetch, or your own utility function, you can jest.spyOn that. hope this helps

Comment: this is the only correct way that does not cause act error

Answer (score 15):

It's a little less clear what the source of the interaction is intended to be, but `submit` can be called on the `input` and it appears to fix the test in the sandbox:

```
fireEvent.submit(input);
```

Comment: Author states "I am trying to test that a form submits when the user presses the "Enter" key.". Your answer will not simulate that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67121710/8798220) answer but it's not worked for me because I am using `keydown` listener to check my input.

Please remember, use only `e.key` not `e.keyCode/e.which` its `deperecated`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471635/8798220

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

const Input = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleEnter = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      const value = e.target.value;
      // API CALLING / LOGIC
    }
  };

  return (
    <input
      placeholder="Search..."
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      onKeyDown={handleEnter}
    />
  );
};

it("should submit when pressing enter", async () => {
  const text = "hello";

  render(<Input />);

  const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Search...");
  await userEvent.type(input, `${text}[Enter]`);

  expect(input).toHaveValue(text);
  // check about enter logic.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit by button but the event target will be the button and not the form. To resolve this:

- submit the form
- useRef on the form
- ByTestId on the form

Submitting the form is only accessible if it has an [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name). In this sense, using `role="my-form"` (ByRole) or `aria-label="form's purpose"` (ByLabelText or ByRole("form")).

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { getByRole, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/dom';

test("test form", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  div.innerHTML = `
  <form role="my-form">
    <label for="first_name">
      First Name:
      <input id="first_name" type="text" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  `;

  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  div.querySelector('form').onsubmit = handleSubmit;

  fireEvent.submit(getByRole(div, "my-form"));
  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Just FYI that `my-form` is not a valid ARIA role. Please make sure to use valid ARIA roles. In this case simply `role="form"`. More info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to force it without any changes or new libraries as follow

```
const btnDeepPropsKey = Object.keys(
  wrapper.getByTestId('input-search')
)?.find(item => item?.includes('__reactProps'))

await waitFor(async () =>
  (wrapper.getByTestId('input-search') as any)?.[
    btnDeepPropsKey
  ]?.onKeyPress({ key: 'Enter' })
)
```

If you can't reach that prop you can log it as well

```
console.log(wrapper.getByTestId("input-search"))
```

Note that some states may have been lost if you try to access any other onKeyPress of those props that was shown in log above

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar solution, in my case I needed the form to call a method when they hit enter, I'm using angular 9.1.

```
it('should call loginFromKey when enter key is pressed', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const loginFromKeySpy = jest.spyOn(component, 'loginFromKey');

  const formElement: HTMLElement = queryNativeElement('form');
  expect(formElement).toBeTruthy();

  formElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Enter' }));

  expect(loginFromKeySpy).toBeCalled();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To simulate keyboard show/hide I first focus on input and then simulate typing. This way you can fire `onSubmitEditing` event to simulate submit button pressed on a Keyboard.

```
import { fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native'

const input = getByTestId('input');
fireEvent.focus(input);
fireEvent.changeText(input, 'hello world')
fireEvent.submitEditing(input);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing the correct options to `fireEvent.keyDown` event. Try to pass `keyCode: 13` along with `key: "enter"`

The following piece of code works for me

```
it('Check if added todo show in list with label', () => {
  render(<TodoApp/>)
  const input = screen.getByTestId('add-todo')

  fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: 'Task with label @health'}});
  fireEvent.keyDown(input, {key: 'enter', keyCode: 13})

  const todoList = screen.getByTestId('todo-list')
  expect(todoList).toHaveTextContent('health')
});
```