# Alternatives to event.which and event.keyCode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I tried to use the event.which and event.keyCode in my JavaScript code today and got a line ruled across each. I read that both have been deprecated on my VSCode.

Does anyone know the alternatives to them?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/keycode-vs-which?

Comment: Use [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) instead.

Comment: VSCode is being strict about 'event'. If you add a parameter `function (event)` - or 'ev' or whatever - to your event-handling function, then 'event' becomes available inside the function, rather than the function getting the global 'event', which is one reason VSCode crosses out 'event'. There are others cases, but this one is a common error.

Answer (score 1):

To determine what character corresponds with the key event, you need to use **event.key** instead. The events **which/keyCode** are indeed deprecated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`event.keyCode` is deprecated , although some browsers do support it.
Use `event.code` instead.

Read **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Example)** on how to implement crossbrowser for complete support