# How i can write in arabic keyboard in this code

Tags: javascript

I have tried write a code that listen to my keyboard(arabic keyboard)
I have issue my code its only read english keyboard
I tried many times to solve this problem but without any luck
Any advice?

```
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        processInput(e);
    })
}

function processKey() {
    e = { "code" : this.id };
    processInput(e);
}

function processInput(e) {
    if (gameOver) return; 


    if ("Keyأ" <= e.code && e.code <= "Keyي") {
        if (col < width) {
            let currTile = document.getElementById(row.toString() + '-' + col.toString());
            if (currTile.innerText == "") {
                currTile.innerText = e.code[3];
                col += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (e.code == "Backspace") {
        if (0 < col && col <= width) {
            col -=1;
        }
        let currTile = document.getElementById(row.toString() + '-' + col.toString());
        currTile.innerText = "";
    }

    else if (e.code == "Enter") {
        update();
    }

    if (!gameOver && row == height) {
        gameOver = true;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerText = word;
    }
}
```

I tried to import a libary called Javascript-Arabic-Reshaper
but didnt work for me

Comment: why `python` tag,or `html` or `css`? Please, don't spam tags.

Comment: `e.code` is the hardwired key of your keyboard-layout. There is `e.key`. https://blog.andri.co/022-should-i-use-ecode-or-ekey-when-handling-keyboard-events/ . https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471635/2569323 .

Answer (score 0):

I am new to StackOverflow platform and first time using it,
but Thanks to deEr got me more understanding in keyboardevents

this is how I solve it

> by changing e.code to e.key and removed "Keyأ" to just "أ"

```
    // on keyboard input typing
if ("أ" <= e.key && e.key <= "ي") { 
    if (col < width) {
        let currTile = document.getElementById(row.toString() + '-' + col.toString());
        if (currTile.innerText == "") {
            currTile.innerText = e.key;
            col += 1;
        }
    }
}
// on mouse click it works
else if ("Keyأ" <= e.code && e.code <= "Keyي") {
    if (col < width) {
        let currTile = document.getElementById(row.toString() + '-' + col.toString());
        if (currTile.innerText == "") {
            currTile.innerText = e.code[3];
            col += 1;
        }
    }
}
```