# How do I get the maximum value of strings like '1.2.5.4' and '1.2.5.3'?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with strings comprising of numbers in a dotted notation as such:

```
var arr = ['1.2.5.4', '1.2.5.3'];
```

I would like to be able to find the string that denotes the highest value.

I already tried

```
Math.max.apply(null, arr)
```

Since there are multiple decimals, it simply won't work.

Comment: `var arr = [1.2.5.4, 1.2.5.3];` is not valid code. You should be getting an interpreter error on this. It should be `var arr = ['1.2.5.4', '1.2.5.3'];` And, as to which is the max, hard to tell. How do you sort them? Left-first or right-first?

Comment: Those are strings, not numbers.

Comment: These are not `earthly` numbers.

Comment: Sorry, those should be strings!

Comment: I'd strip the non-numeric characters and then treat the results as ints

Comment: What should this "max value" return?  Are these like "version numbers" for software?

Comment: Is it still possible to get the maximum value out of them with a pre-existing functions?

Comment: In the exemple its 1.2.5.4 the biggest value. Yes they can be treated as software versions. So 1.3.24.1 would be bigger then 1.3.

Comment: @hafichuk: That sounds like it'd work, but there may be cases where it won't (maybe?).

Comment: What's the "max" value in this example: `var arr = ['cheese','1.4.3','6.4'];`

Comment: The array containing the values won't have words but only a series of my weird version numbers to be compared.

Comment: @hafichuk That may work for simple examples, but would fail with say `'1.24.2.1'` and `1.2.52.1'`. `1.24 > 1.2`, but `12421 < 12521`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java may help.

Comment: @Louis, so there will never be any letters such as `1.3a.2` or anything, right?

Comment: Correct, only numbers will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a simpler solution:

```
function latest (versions) {
  versions.sort (function (a, b) {
    a = a.split ('.');
    b = b.split ('.');   
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length && a[i] === b[i]; i++);
    return ((i === a.length) || (+a[i] < +b[i])) ? 1 : -1;
  });
  return versions[0]; 
}

[
  latest (['1.2.5.4', '1.3.5.3', '1.2.3.4.5', '1.24.2.1', '1.2.52']),
  latest (['1.2.5.4', '1.3.5.3', '1.2.3.4.5', '1.2.52']),
  latest (['1.2.5.4', '1.2.3.4.5', '1.2.52']),
  latest (['1.2.5.4', '1.2.3.4.5'])
]

/* Displays on JS console

    ["1.24.2.1", "1.3.5.3", "1.2.52", "1.2.5.4"]
*/
```

Thanks for the vote, on review I noted a bug which I have corrected in the code above.

Comment: Warning : this function sorts the original array ! You should use de `reduce` function instead, to "reduce the array to a single value, aka the latest version" instead of sorting it and taking the first item.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create your own sorting subroutine for this, since they're to be treated as version numbers. You'll want to do a left-first comparison, comparing each number delimited by periods.

Here's a good bit of code stolen from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number) that does exactly as I mentioned:

```
function assert(x) {
    if (!x) {
        alert("Assert failed");
        debugger;
    }
}

function isPositiveInteger(x) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019526/11236
    return /^\d+$/.test(x);
}

/**
 * Compare two software version numbers (e.g. 1.7.1)
 * Returns:
 *
 *  0 if they're identical
 *  negative if v1 < v2
 *  positive if v1 > v2
 *  Nan if they in the wrong format
 *
 *  E.g.:
 *
 *  assert(version_number_compare("1.7.1", "1.6.10") > 0);
 *  assert(version_number_compare("1.7.1", "1.7.10") < 0);
 *
 *  "Unit tests": http://jsfiddle.net/ripper234/Xv9WL/28/
 *
 *  Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832721/11236
 */
function compareVersionNumbers(v1, v2){
    var v1parts = v1.split('.');
    var v2parts = v2.split('.');

    // First, validate both numbers are true version numbers
    function validateParts(parts) {
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
            if (!isPositiveInteger(parts[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (!validateParts(v1parts) || !validateParts(v2parts)) {
        return NaN;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < v1parts.length; ++i) {
        if (v2parts.length === i) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (v1parts[i] === v2parts[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        if (v1parts[i] > v2parts[i]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    if (v1parts.length != v2parts.length) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7.1", "1.7.10") < 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.6.1", "1.7.10") < 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.6.20", "1.7.10") < 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7.1", "1.7.10") < 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7", "1.7.0") < 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7", "1.8.0") < 0);

assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7.10", "1.7.1") > 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7.10", "1.6.1") > 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7.10", "1.6.20") > 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7.0", "1.7") > 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.8.0", "1.7") > 0);

assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7.10", "1.7.10") === 0);
assert(compareVersionNumbers("1.7", "1.7") === 0);

assert(isNaN(compareVersionNumbers("1.7", "1..7")));
assert(isNaN(compareVersionNumbers("1.7", "Bad")));
assert(isNaN(compareVersionNumbers("1..7", "1.7")));
assert(isNaN(compareVersionNumbers("Bad", "1.7")));

alert("All done");
​
```

Comment: WARNING: This appears to give the incorrect answer for certain minor versions:
`compareVersionNumbers("1.7.10", "1.66.10")` produces `1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a human sort implementation:

```
Array.prototype.humanSort = function() {
  return this.sort(function(a, b) {
    aa = a.split('.');
    bb = b.split('.');

    for(var x = 0; x < Math.max(aa.length, bb.length); x++) {
      if(aa[x] != bb[x]) {
        var cmp1 = (isNaN(parseInt(aa[x],10)))? aa[x] : parseInt(aa[x],10);
        var cmp2 = (isNaN(parseInt(bb[x],10)))? bb[x] : parseInt(bb[x],10);
        if(cmp1 == undefined || cmp2 == undefined)
          return aa.length - bb.length;
        else
          return (cmp1 < cmp2) ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
 ['1.12.5.4', '1.2.5.3'].humanSort(); // => ['1.2.5.3', '1.12.5.4']
```

Comment: Have you tested the above code for all the scenarios mentioned in the comments as a minimum?

Comment: 1.12.5.4 Would have to be greater then 1.2.5.3. Since 12 > 2.

Comment: I tested it for all the scenarios mentioned in the comments. The sort algorithm provided sorts the elements in ascending order, meaning the last element in the sorted array is the largest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 'better' solution on my opinion (because the checked one modifies the original array, and this is evil ;) ) :

```
function latest(versions) {
    return versions.reduce(function(latest, current){
        var l = latest.split('.'),
            c = current.split('.');
        for (var i=0,len=Math.min(l.length, c.length); i<len; i++){
            if (+l[i] === +c[i]) {
                continue;
            } else {
                return +l[i] < +c[i] ? current : latest;
            }
        }
        return l.length < c.length ? current : latest;
    }, "0");
}
```

The results are exactly the same than the checked answer, except the original array is still pristine.

```
[
  latest (['1.2.5.4', '1.3.5.3', '1.2.3.4.5', '1.24.2.1', '1.2.52']),
  latest (['1.2.5.4', '1.3.5.3', '1.2.3.4.5', '1.2.52']),
  latest (['1.2.5.4', '1.2.3.4.5', '1.2.52']),
  latest (['1.2.5.4', '1.2.3.4.5'])
]

/* Displays on JS console

    ["1.24.2.1", "1.3.5.3", "1.2.52", "1.2.5.4"]
*/
```

And it takes advantage from the `reduce` function, which is exactly made for this usage.