# PHP validate integer is not functioning

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an error box pop up when theres letters inside of the textbox, however it is not working and I'm not sure what I need to do.

Here is  the code for the section

```
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;&nbsp;Weight:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="weight"  value="<?php echo $weight?>" onblur="validateinteger(Diamonds.weight,'weight')" <?php if($formmode==1) echo 'disabled';?> size="15" /></td>
 </tr>
```

I'm new to this website so I'm not sure how to post all the codes here therefore I uploaded everything to pastebin.

For complete code please click. http://pastebin.com/ZfUe6GWq

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a javascript issue not a php one

Comment: Check console in your browser (usually could be opened with F12, may need to install Firebug in FireFox). See if there are some errors.

Comment: What is not working? What do you get?

Comment: @nl-x nothing at all, it just allows the letter to sit there without showing any error msg

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you should modify your `validateinger` function.
First, take a look at [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) specification. You should remember that it will return a number even if parameter is not completely a number. For instance:
`parseInt("12px")`  will return `12`. Because of that, you should better simply test value with [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) (which will return true in case if value is "12px"):

```
function validateinteger(whichcontrol, controlname){
   if(whichcontrol.value.length==0)
     return true;
   else if(isNaN(whichcontrol.value))
     alert(controlname + " must be a number!"); 
   else
     return true;
  }
```

But above code will only check if string is a number, not integer (like function name says).
To check if value is exactly integer, you may do next (using regexp):

```
function validateinteger(whichcontrol, controlname){
   if(whichcontrol.value.length==0)
     return true;
   else if(!(/^[\d]+$/.test(whichcontrol.value)​))
     alert(controlname + " must be a number!"); 
   else
     return true;
}
```

(based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019526/1558311)  answer)

**Note:**

Instead of `onblur="validateinteger(Diamonds.weight,'weight')"`you may do `onblur="validateinteger(this,'weight')"`. Where `this` points to an element where event happens.