# validate a string is non-negative whole number in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, integer

This is a solution for validating an integer. Can someone please explain the logic of [Karim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019526/2455855).
This works perfectly, but i am not able to understand how.

```
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
if(intRegex.test(someNumber)) {
   alert('I am an int');
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think this question should better be a comment on that answer… and should be answered there by @Karim himself.

Comment: Note that this code is not entirely correct. For example, it validates a string like `000...(10,000 times)..000` which is hardly a "number".

Answer (score 15):

The regex: `/^\d+$/`

```
^ // beginning of the string
\d //  numeric char [0-9]
+ // 1 or more from the last
$ // ends of the string
```

when they are all combined:

From the beginning of the string to the end there are one or more numbers char[0-9] and number only.

Answer (score 5):

Check out a Regular Expression reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

```
/^\d+$/
^ : Start of string
\d : A number [0-9]
+ : 1 or more of the previous
$ : End of string
```

Answer (score 0):

## What is a Nonnegative Whole Number?

> A Nonnegative whole number is an "integer that is either 0 or positive."
>
> Source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonnegativeInteger.html

In other words, you are looking to validate a nonnegative integer.

The answers above are insufficient because they do not include integers such as `-0` and `-0000`, which, technically, after parsing, become nonnegative integers. The other answers also do not validate integers with `+` in front.

**You can use the following regex for validation:**

```
/^(\+?\d+|-?0+)$/
```

**[Try it Online!](https://regexr.com/3ld4i)**

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # Beginning of String
    (               # Capturing Group
            \+?     # Optional '+' Sign
            \d+     # One or More Digits (0 - 9)
        |           # OR
            -?      # Optional '-' Sign
            0+      # One or More 0 Digits
    )               # End Capturing Group
$                   # End of String
```

The following test cases return true: `-0`, `-0000`, `0`, `00000`, `+0`, `+0000`, `1`, `12345`, `+1`, `+1234`.
The following test cases return false: `-12.3`, `123.4`, `-1234`, `-1`.

**Note:** *This regex does not work for integer strings written in scientific notation.*

Answer (score -1):

This regex may be better `/^[1-9]+\d*$/`

```
^     // beginning of the string
[1-9] // numeric char [1-9]
+     // 1 or more occurrence of the prior
\d    // numeric char [0-9]
*     // 0 or more occurrences of the prior
$     // end of the string
```

Will also test against non-negative integers that are pre-padded with zeroes

Comment: This will fail on '0'.